# PHP IMAP Extensions On Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, imap

We have a digital ocean server, running Active Collab, which uses IMAP extensions for fetching email

On Apache you would run the php_imap.dll extension (in php.ini) however this module only runs on Apache

Does anyone know of anything which runs on nginx?

Comment: Please add config blocks to support your question.

Comment: The php_imap.dll has nothing to do with the webserver. It's a PHP extension.

Comment: maybe the problem is getting imap installed then

ive run all the normal things

sudo apt get php5_imap etc (as per many google results)
but on turning on in php.ini, I get dynamic library not found etc.